# What will Z3 return when model_completion is set to false?

Tags: c++, c, model, z3

When querying a model, with `model_completion` set to `false` in `Z3_model_eval`: What will Z3 return to signify that an interpretation is a "don't care"?

In case someone wants to suggest that: I guess it's probably not the return value of the function `Z3_model_eval`, since the `z3++.h` file (the C++ API) contains the lines:

```
Z3_bool status = Z3_model_eval(ctx(), m_model, n, model_completion, &r);
check_error();
if (status == Z3_FALSE)
    throw exception("failed to evaluate expression");
```

In general: How does Z3 signify that a certain constant is a "don't care" in a model?

Comment: Size `Z3_model_eval` is not a standard C++ function, please edit your post to provide the declaration and definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For true don't-cares, the model will not assign any value. Consequently, calls to `eval` or `Z3_model_eval` with model_completion set to `false` will keep the original constants untouched and only replace those for which a model value is assigned (and it will potentially simplify the expression). Here's an example:

```
context c;
expr e = c.int_const("x");

solver s(c);
s.add(e == e);
model m = s.get_model();

std::cout << m.eval(e, false) << std::endl;
std::cout << m.eval(e, true) << std::endl;
```

Note that the first line of output prints `x`, i.e., the original expression is untouched, while the call to eval with model_completion set to `true` will print `0`.